# How to understand this sentence correctly: "He shambled off down the corridor."

Tags: meaning

"Off down the corridor"?

"off" and "down"?

I can't get the picture of this sentence,because I don't know where the man was and where he was going in the sentence.  What position did the speaker think "he" was in then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *off* goes with *shambled*:

> He shambled off into the distance.
>   He shambled off across the room.
>   He shambled off out of the barroom.

You could write any of those without using the *off*:

> He shambled into the distance.
>   He shambled across the room.
>   He shambled out of the barroom.

The *off* simply helps emphasize that the person was leaving his initial location. As NOAD says:

> **off** (*adv.*) away from the place in question : *the man ran off* | *she dashed off to her room*

This should make *down the corridor* make more sense – it simply describes where he shambled off to. He could have "shambled off" anywhere, but, in your sentence, he shambled off *down the corridor* (which means *toward one end of the corridor*).